# Deploying the BIRT report in GlassFish/TomCat

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat, glassfish, birt

I encounter some problems deploying birt viewer in glassfish.

I deployed birt viewer (birt-runtime-4_4_2) on tomcat and glassfish and attached some screenshots to be more clear. The problem occurs in glassfish, where I got some errors.

[See Image](http://i61.tinypic.com/33xc212.jpg)

- Due to my reputation I cannot post multiple screenshots, but you can find the tomcat screenshot on actuate forum.

In tomcat everything works fine!

Somebody had this problem in the past ? (I googled for 2 days and I can't find any solution to my problem)

- I posted this question to [actuate forum](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/36592-deploying-the-birt-report-in-glassfishtomcat/) to.

Comment: It is common practice to include a summary of external links in this post. It is also common practice to include code. It is also common practice to include errors as text in this post, not as images. I doubt anyone is able or willing to help you this way

Comment: This is not a code error problem, because if it was, the deployment in tomcat wouldn't work.

Comment: Then how is it jsf or jsp related?

Comment: I think glassfish/tomcat may have different implementations of JSF (Mojarra) and this may cause the problem.

Comment: Then you have a stacktrace in your server logging. Post that…